# Aligning variables vertically in a cases environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, cases

I'm creating a system of equations in LaTeX, using a `cases` environment, with variables $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ and $x_4$. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,onecolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{math}
        \begin{cases}
             x_1 +  x_2 + x_3 +  x_4 =  3\\
                 - 3x_2 + x_3 - 2x_4 = -3\\
                         2x_3 + 5x_4 = -3\\
                              - 7x_4 = -7
        \end{cases}
    \end{math}
\end{document}
```

I would like to keep the variables vertically aligned in the output, as they appear in the source code above. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cases` environment is probably not the best tool for your purpose. You may instead want to look into using the [systeme](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/systeme) package and the associated macro `\systeme`.

The following example illustrates the usage of this macro. The only manual adjustment I've applied is for the RHS term in the first equation, where I've added a `\phantom{-}` term to adjust the alignment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{systeme}
\begin{document}
\begin{math}
\systeme{
x_1 +  x_2 + x_3 +  x_4 =  \phantom{-}3,
- 3x_2 + x_3 - 2x_4 = -3,
2x_3 + 5x_4 = -3,
- 7x_4 = -7}
\end{math}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The preceding look *could* actually be achieved via a `cases` environment, as follows:

```
\begin{math}
\begin{cases}
\hfill x_1 + \phantom{2}x_2 + \phantom{2}x_3 + \phantom{2}x_4 = \phantom{-}3\\
\hfill {}- 3x_2 + \phantom{2}x_3 - 2x_4 = -3\\
\hfill 2x_3 + 5x_4 = -3\\
\hfill {}- 7x_4 = -7
\end{cases}
\end{math}
```

However, compared with the work required when using the `systeme` package, four `\hfill`instructions, three extra `\phantom` instructions, and two `{}` empty groups are required to get the job done. I guess everyone will agree that `systeme` is the much better tool for this job...

Comment: I never knew of the system package. Would be nice to have the manual in english!